# How do I create method that blocks until a file is detected?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

I want to use it this way

```
detectedFile = Wait(directory, filter);
```

The most primitive way is to use loop, like

```
while(true)
{
   var found = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, filter).FirstOrDefault();
   if(found != null) return found;
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could use FileSystemWatcher, rather than blocking? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: actually, I want to block

Comment: you can still use `FileSystemWatcher.OnCreated` to put the trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) instance and use the WaitForChanged method, passing it [WatcherChangeTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6xf43e0.aspx).Created.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block your thread but search if a file exists I would use `FileSystemWatcher` as Blorgbeard suggested on a separate thread and block your main thread using something like this...

```
 ManualResetEventSlim fileDetected = new ManualResetEventSlim();
 fileDetected.Reset(); // sets or makes sure signal is false
 fileDetected.Wait();  // waits for signal to be set true
 fileDetected.Set();   // sets signal to true
```